# Zip/Postal Code to Coordinate in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, geocoding

I try to get coordinate from zip/postal code using objective-c in iOS, however, it always return fixed coordinates in Zhengzhou, China on my own iPhone (I guess it is the factory of Foxconn,[34.153348, 113.488374]). But it works fine on simulator.

```
CLGeocoder *geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geoCoder geocodeAddressString:zipcodefield.text completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
    CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;
    NSLog(@"%f", coordinate.latitude);
    NSLog(@"%f", coordinate.longitude);
}];
```

Do you guys know why? Thanks.

Comment: probably locations services is off in your apple device ..

Comment: @vaibhav sorry, I don't think so. I turned it on and this function just translate the text to coordinates.

Comment: Is `zipcodefield` just a zipcode? It sounds like you need to try to use an actual address, rather than a zipcode for `geocodeAddressString` (based on the documentation).